# disabling the direct login for super user (common super user account) and other users (not having the sudo access) need to switch as super user

Tags: login, nologin

We have a common superuser account ("cmn_usr") with sudo access, and separate normal user accounts ("nml_usr") without sudo access. Currently, normal users can directly log in as the superuser ("cmn_usr") and able to switch as superuser ("cmn_usr"). For security reasons, we want to disable direct login for superuser ("cmn_usr") and should be protected  while still allowing normal users ("nml_usr") to switch to it when needed.

While I've researched possible solutions online, none seem to align with our organization's IT security best practices. If a similar question regarding disabling direct login for a privileged account while facilitating user switching has been addressed here with an IT-approved answer, I apologize for the redundancy and would appreciate if you could direct me to it

Thank you very much.
Hariharasudhan C

Comment: `sudo` will to do exactly want you describe. If it's unsuitable you need to explain why

Comment: Currently, both nml_usr and cmn_usr accounts allow direct login, posing a configuration change risk. To enhance security and maintain change tracking, we need to implement a solution that blocks direct login only for cmn_usr [Direct login from PuTTY or other app, the server not having the DEl]. But preserving sudo access through sudo su - cmn_usr. Attempts to restrict cmn_usr login using passwd lock, /sbin/false, and nologin have proven ineffective.

Comment: Please add the extra detail to your question so that it's easy for everyone to see. By the way, _do not_ use `sudo su`; there's no point whatsoever. Just use `sudo`, possibly as either `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`. I still don't see why `sudo` isn't the answer here

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is your solution; `sudo su` is not.

> We have a common superuser account ("cmn_usr") with sudo access, and separate normal user accounts ("nml_usr") without sudo access.

For good security practice you should not be sharing the "cmn_usr" account. There's no auditable action log if you do that. Give each of your administrators their own login.

> Currently, normal users can directly log in as the superuser ("cmn_usr")

As above, that should be a security no no.

> For security reasons, we want to disable direct login for superuser ("cmn_usr") and should be protected while still allowing normal users ("nml_usr") to switch to it when needed

Your proposed solution is to require "nml_usr" accounts (I really hope that's a collection not a single account) to become "cnm_usr" so that they can then become root to perform privileged operations? That seems very strange.

First, stop using `su`. It looks at the target user's shell, which since you have correctly disabled it, prevents it doing anything useful.

Allow your normal users to `sudo -u cmn_usr -s`. Then allow "cmn_usr" to `sudo -s`. Requirement achieved.

But I still don't see why your permitted set of "nml_usr" accounts can't just `sudo {privileged action}` and be done with it. You get an auditable entry in the logs recording who (which user account) has done what ("privileged action").